# Effectively bypass chatgpt cloudflare by using different proxy package or different cloud service provider in restricted countries

Tags: amazon-ec2, proxy, chatbot, vpn, cloudflare

I have an account in chatgpt but as I located in the restricted country, I tried to use AWS proxy (US server) to login chatgpt. Few weeks ago it worked but now I get an error message `access denied error code 1020`. I used tinyproxy in stealth mode at first but since I was unable to pass through the cloudflare, I guessed probably the proxy was not good enough to disguise itself as a proxy, so I tried squid vpn in stealth mode  and algo vpn, but all did not work(Tried other AWS countries server as well other than US). Until now, I figure out chatgpt might probably just banned all connection from amazon or perhaps my proxy is just not smart enough to pass through cloudflare? What are more options? Any recommended free vpn proxy that I could installed into my AWS EC2 or perhaps I should try other less known cloud services instead? e.g. (other non-restricted country's local cloud services) Besides, I have consider using other free proxy from the internet but as I need to login my gmail, is it danger to do so but since its https so my username and password should be encrypted?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem, simple ssh tunneling works you can use a jump server to bypass your country first and than use different server to use as proxy because some of your vps servers get banned with IP, so you may have to use another vpn with different proxy

```
ssh -D "port to make SOCKS 5 Connection like" <10808> -J <"user">@<"jump server IP"> <"user">@<"final server IP">
```

than you can use "foxyproxy" extention to build SOCKS5 proxy that uses specified port in this example 10808 to route your browser terrafic through tunnel in port 10808 to final server

or you can use something like sshuttle, but i was fine with this simple tunneling method in GFW